# No UUID in dsym file generated by Xcode 44

Tags: ios, xcode, crash-reports, symbolicatecrash

I am facing issues with the UUID, after the ipa or .app file is generated dsym file is also getting generated properly, but the problem which i face is there is no association between the .app and .dsym.

usually an uuid is gets generated dsym file is created and that is used to map the crash logs for symbolizing the same.

i am not sure whether the issue is with some project settings, but need your help to fix this issue.

When i right click the dsym file->get info->more information the place is empty it is not having any uuid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The finder info screen doesn't always show the UUID, even tough it's there.

Simply check it in the terminal via: `dwarfdump --uuid YourApp.app.dSYM`

The same works with the app binary via: `dwarfdump --uuid YourApp.app/YourAppExecutable`

It's very very unlikely that a dSYM that is generated in the same run as you build the app, doesn't get the same UUID.

Comment: thank you so much kerni, there was a misunderstanding because of that, for your information it did not symbolicate the crash logs instead organizer quickly remove the symbolicating status. later i used symobilcatecrash command to link them together and atlast it started putting logs properly.